How to set refresh token in cookies for OpenIddict Asp.Net Core
I'm learning OpenIddict follow some samples of them but i didn't find how to set response refresh token in cookies and use the cookie to authenticate. The current behavior I make it work is the Exchange endpoint takes refresh_token in request body and return new access_token and refresh_token in response body
I have success setting up some basic authorization controller endpoints, I just want to use http-only cookies for storing refresh_token. I can't find a way to change this behavior in openiddict document

use this below code to handle token:
public class CustomTokenEndpointHandler : OpenIddictServerEvents
{
    public override Task ProcessSignIn(OpenIddictServerEvents.ProcessSignInContext context)
    {
        var response = context.Transaction.Response;

        // Set the refresh token in an HTTP-only cookie
        context.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append(
            "refresh_token",
            response.RefreshToken,
            new CookieOptions
            {
                HttpOnly = true,
                Secure = true,
                SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict,
                Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(14)
            });

        // Remove the refresh token from the response
        response.RemoveParameter(OpenIddictConstants.Parameters.RefreshToken);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

Override the default behavior to read the refresh token from the cookie:
public class CustomTokenExchangeHandler : OpenIddictServerEvents
{
    public override async Task ProcessAuthentication(OpenIddictServerEvents.ProcessAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        // Check if the request is for token exchange and contains a refresh token grant type
        if (context.Request.IsTokenRequest() && context.Request.IsRefreshTokenGrantType())
        {
            // Read the refresh token from the cookie
            if (context.HttpContext.Request.Cookies.TryGetValue("refresh_token", out var refreshToken))
            {
                context.Request.RefreshToken = refreshToken;
            }
            else
            {
                context.Reject(
                    error: OpenIddictConstants.Errors.InvalidGrant,
                    description: "The refresh token is missing.");
            }
        }

        await base.ProcessAuthentication(context);
    }
}

now register the handle in program.cs file

Thank you so much, I've missed the event handler part in their document. The new version code is quite bit different but I figured it out
